# Connect to JMS queue on WebLogic through Mule 4

Tags: jms, weblogic, jndi, mule4

I'm trying to connect to a JMS queue on WebLogic through Mule 4, but I'm not able to find any information regarding the configuration. Is it possible to subscribe to WebLogic queue without having username and password? I have JNDI context URL only which is of t3 protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Mule 4 has a [JMS connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/jms-connector/1.8/) to connect to JMS message brokers. First you need to know how to connect to WebLogic Queue using JMS, for example in a Java application. Once you understand that configuration, then translate it to using the JMS connector in Mule. For example the connector allows the usage of JNDI connections. Remember to add the proper client libraries for Weblogic JMS to the Mule application project.

If it is possible at all to connect without user and password will depend on what the Weblogic and your installation allows.

I found this example configuration of the JMS connector for Weblogic. You may need a different configuration for your installation.

Example:

```xml
<jms:config name="JMS_Config_Weblogic" doc:name="JMS Config"  >
    <jms:generic-connection username="myuser" password="mypassword">
        <jms:connection-factory >
           <jms:jndi-connection-factory connectionFactoryJndiName="jms/somejndiname" >
              <jms:custom-jndi-name-resolver >
                  <jms:cached-jndi-name-resolver jndiInitialFactory="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory" jndiProviderUrl="t3://myhost.com:8830" >
                  </jms:cached-jndi-name-resolver>
              </jms:custom-jndi-name-resolver>
           </jms:jndi-connection-factory>
       </jms:connection-factory>
    </jms:generic-connection>
</jms:config>
```